# C# .NET Core API в чем ошибка?

Tags: c#, .net, api

Есть форма в index.html, которая должна делать какое-либо действие при клике на кнопку submit.

```
<form asp-action="Test" asp-controller="File" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="uploadedFile" /><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Загрузить" />
    </form>
```

Вот FileController с тем же методом и POST запросом. Контроллер я вставил сюда пустым, ибо и без кода внутри - ошибка:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Test()
{
    return Ok("GOOD!");
}
```

При нажатии на кнопку случается ошибка в консоли:

> Простой текстовый документ не содержит объявления кодировки символов. Если документ содержит символы, не входящие в диапазон US-ASCII, то в некоторых конфигурациях браузера в документе будет отображён искажённый текст. Кодировка символов файла должна быть объявлена в протоколе передачи или файл должен использовать индикатор порядка байтов (BOM) в качестве сигнатуры кодировки.

То ли лыжи не едут - то ли руки кривые, но в чем может быть проблема? Проект на .Net Core 3.1 API

Comment: Видимо хочет чтобы ваш index.html был в кодировке "utf8 with BOM"

Comment: @vitidev он включен по умолчанию

Comment: Вы уже удалили файл index.html, создали  заново и внесли разметку ручками без `Ctrl+V` ?

Comment: Это не похоже на ошибку, скорее на предупреждение. Оно точно не работает?